# Can we include php files in jasmine and use their functionalities ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

Since jasmine is to used for testing JavaScript and how about adding or including php files in the jasmine environment folder and can access those files it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is a good idea in all honesty. That said there is an npm module that enables the running of PHP files with node/express.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express

It hasn't been updated in quite a while, so I'd be weary about using it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible, but I can't imagine a situation why you would *want* to run PHP files in Jasmine.

Why do you want too? If those PHP files contain already existing functionality then you are probably best to just rewrite them in JavaScript.

Comment: Basically am trying to write code for admin and a user using javascript which i already have my php files can i able to use them in  since am very new to jasmine i do not really know how to use or will be used?

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to learn JavaScript, trying to use PHP files in JavaScript seems insane.